# Matplotlib breaks my monitors. How do I start debugging this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-14.04, gnome

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using gnome3 and I have two monitors, one is horizontal and one is vertical.

I have a rather complicated matplotlib script that has some interaction. 
I also have a version of the script without interaction.

If I run the script with interaction my monitors crash and reset positions (my vertical monitor becomes horizontal).
This does not happen if I run without interactions.

When the crash happens my program still seems to be running, but the terminal is not locatable on the screen. I can find it by alt-tabing, but it wont show up on screen.

Comment: Please specify which GUI toolkit you are using, and whether there are any Xsession error.

Comment: as a workaround, and not really answering your question, you could try changing matplotlib's backend.

Comment: Qt4Agg is the backend. I will try changing it to GTK